# R Shiny downloadButton error in Internet Explorer 8

Tags: r, shiny

Running the following minimal case:

```
library(shiny)
runApp(list(
    ui = bootstrapPage(downloadButton("myDownload")),
    server = function(input, output) {
        output$myDownload <- downloadHandler(
            filename = function() "mtcars.txt",
            content = function(file) write.table(mtcars, file),
            contentType = ".txt"
        )
    }
))
```

which looks like:

[image]

yields the below error in Internet Explorer 8.0.7601 when I click the download button:

[image]

Anyone know why this is happening?

Comment: I'm not sure `contentType = ".txt"` is correct, try to remove it.

Comment: @StéphaneLaurent Thanks, I have tried your suggestion but I still face the same issue. Although I am now able to get to the *file download* prompt with the `open`, `save` and `cancel` buttons, clicking `save` gives me the same error message. Clicking `open` takes me to a blank page.

Answer (score 2):

Cannot recreate the problem, since I do not have IE 8. But I have remembered this thread, which talks about incompatibilty of `shiny` with Internet explorer lower than 10:
[shiny-discuss/websockets](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!searchin/shiny-discuss/websockets$20ie$208/shiny-discuss/tqeURyiPmFI/_PkQ-RxL-3wJ)

So I would suggest you upgrade your browser (your code works on my Internet Explorer 10, for example.)

Answer (score 1):

does your code works with other browser like firefox or chrome? Past i have faced similar problem in download data thing. in `downloadHandaler` where data is getting generated i have assigned it as a global variable. after that is started working, i guess.